# SQL SUM not adding up correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server, math, accounting

I am working on a database for my wife's business to track cost of goods sold (COGS) for tax purposes. For some reason the math just isn't matching what I see on my receipt or calculator. Specifically, in this use case I am off one penny. I have five fields which all decimal(19,4). The calculation for each is as follows:

- Item Cost: What was spent on the item
- Item Premium: Item Cost + (Item Cost * .10)
- Item Tax: (Item Cost + Item Premium) * .06
- Item Transaction Fee: (Item Cost + Item Premium + Item Tax) * .05

In SQL the number matches what I see in Excel, however; that is not matching what I see on my receipt and if I use my calculator to manually add up all of the columns I get $203.24 which is the expected value. Below is a copy of my data that I am using to get the "bad" calculation. Each category is adding up to exactly what it should be based on the line items on the receipt, but the total is one penny off. I need this to be accurate so any help would be appreciated.

Here is a copy of the function I use to calculate the values. The code varies slightly depending on the value I am calculating.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[CalculateTotalFinanceFee]
(
    @EventID int,
    @ItemCost decimal(19,4)
)
RETURNS DECIMAL(19,4)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @Total decimal(19,4)
Set @Total = 0.00

--Premium cost
DECLARE @Premium decimal(19,4)
SELECT @Premium = CASE WHEN sup.SupplierType = 'Auction' THEN CAST((@ItemCost * sup.SupplierPremium) as decimal(19,4)) ELSE 0 END
FROM Events ev
LEFT JOIN Suppliers sup ON sup.ID = ev.SupplierID
WHERE ev.ID = @EventID

-- Tax
DECLARE @Tax decimal(19,4)
SELECT @Tax = CASE WHEN ev.TaxPaid = 1 THEN CAST((@ItemCost + @Premium) * tx.TaxRate as decimal(19,4)) ELSE 0 END
FROM Events ev 
LEFT JOIN Suppliers sup ON sup.ID = ev.SupplierID
LEFT JOIN Taxes tx ON tx.State = sup.SupplierLocation
WHERE ev.ID = @EventID

-- Finance Fee (Credit Card Charge)
DECLARE @FinanceFee decimal(19,4)
SELECT @FinanceFee = CASE WHEN ISNULL(sup.SupplierFinanceFee,0) <> 0 THEN CAST((@ItemCost + @premium + @Tax) * sup.SupplierFinanceFee as decimal(19,4)) ELSE 0 END
                                    FROM Events ev 
                                    LEFT JOIN Suppliers sup ON sup.ID = ev.SupplierID
                                    LEFT JOIN Taxes tx ON tx.State = sup.SupplierLocation
                                    WHERE ev.ID = @EventID

--Set total cost
SET @Total = @FinanceFee
```

[image]

Comment: It's probably a rounding error because you're using `decimal(19,4)` in your code but when you add them up on your calculator you're effectively using `decimal(19,2)`. Changing the code to use `decimal(19,2)` ought to yield the same results

Comment: As a quick test I used decimal 19,2 in excel and I am still short a penny.

Comment: The `,4` in `decimal(19,4)` is the scale and means you have four digits to play with after the decimal point. If you multiply decimal(19,4) values by 0.01, for example, you're truncating any values that were in the third and fourth decimal places and would have appeared in the fifth and sixth decimal places. Would you get your cent back if you cast everything to decimal(19,6), sum your values and return the final result as decimal(19,4)?

Comment: Firstly, make sure you are using decimal(19,2) throughout. Every amount must be a real money amount, else the fractions will add up in the end and give you more/less than the real world. Then find the actual line and value that is off from what you are expecting. And analyse the computation to work out why. This is very common accounting issue, ensuring you make your rounding match whatever the other party is going.

Comment: I made everything 19,2 and recalculated. Now my total is 203.37 instead of 203.24. Specifically, I see that the tax and transaction fees are off. The tax is off by .10 and the finance fee is off by .03.